# Edit string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to consistently exctract city names from strings that look like this:

```
{"id":25,"title":"Buenos Aires"}
{"id":26,"title":"Chicago"}
```

I was thinking about starting from 3 rd character from the end and then stopping at second quotation mark but I didnt find the way to do it.

Comment: Is this extracting from a json file or a JavaScript file?

Comment: Simple JSON parsing : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse_json.asp

Comment: thanks, that was easy

Comment: @user1743703 look at Eriks answer below then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is JSON formatted, you can decode it to js objects directly

```
var a = JSON.parse('{"id":25,"title":"Buenos Aires"}'), 
    b = JSON.parse('{"id":26,"title":"Chicago"}');

console.log(a.title); // prints Buenos Aires
console.log(b.title); // prints Chicago
```